# How to automatically switch unit systems?

Tags: siunitx, units

The question [Why use a package to typeset units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107818) made me think about something else: In non-scientific context one may have to provide data for persons using ... imperial units (shiver). But there may be two versions of a report, or the desire to put a secondary unit in parentheses following the primary unit value. Is there any package that treats this? So I'd write something like

```
$\SI{5}{\m/\s}$
```

And the output could be chosen to be any of e.g.

```
5 m/s
5 m/s (11.18 mph)
11.18 mph (18 km/h)
```

depending on a definition in the preamble?

Comment: Sure it is possible, however, consider places were `meter` is compared with the imperial unit `miles`. You should do `\SI{5}{\length/\time}` to conform to some kind of consistency. Furthermore, doing `\let\length\m` or `\let\length\miles` is probably what you need? (there might be something that should be handled correctly in terms of siunitx). And then some wrapper on `\SI`

Comment: @zeroth I think unit conversion is needed here rather than only the symbols. Check 5 becoming 11.18 and 18.

Comment: Yes, I put in the _wrapper on \SI_ to handle this. (my comment was merely noting that `\m` was not always meters which was troubling me).

Comment: @zeroth I think I understand what you mean: providing the SI-unit magnitude, and the `\let`s would have the wrapped `\SI` decide in which actual unit to display. It's a good idea, though that would not provide an intuitive way for the optional parentheses.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler something like that, but the wrapper can also decide the parenthesis notation? Here you probably need to define a "standard" unit and "parenthesised" unit. And then the wrapper could handle both cases, or make several wrapper functions for parenthesised and non-parenthesised versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\speed} [1] {%
  \SI{#1}{\metre\per\second} (\pgfmathparse{2.247*#1}\pgfmathresult~mph)%
}

\begin{document}
  \speed{5}
\end{document}
```

The output can be optimized, but with `pgf` you can define any calculation (like unit conversions, which are basically multiplications with a constant factor).

I don't think there's a finished package yet that supports automatically unit conversions.

Comment: Sounds good. Using Python with [`sympy.physics.units`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/units.html), or [GNU units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/), could of course save the hassle of manually converting...